# How do I separate residue from long long number?

Tags: c, algorithm, cs50

I'm taking the CS50 course on [edx.org](http://edx.org); it's called Introduction to Computer Science.

I'm trying to solve 1st week problem set. So user inputs credit card number and I have to develop some sort of algorithm to check if it's number is valid. To do so I need to separate whole 16-digit number to digits. And I'm stuck here. I guess I need to do this in loop, at getting at each step digit by digit and to do so I wanted to divide user's input by 10 each step and somehow get the residue.

I can't convert to type `int` because of `int`'s restrictions on number of digits it can hold. How can I implement this kind of function? I tried this, but then realized it leads to nothing... At first glance at least. `cre_num` stays for credit number.

```
long long check(long long cre_num)
{
    double part, i;

    for (i = 0.1; i <= 1; i = i+0.1)
    {
        if (cre_num/10 == i)
        {
            part = i;
        }
    }
    return part;
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you a lot, didn't think of this kind of realization.

Comment: The `long long` value `cre_num/10` is never going to equate to a `double` value in the range 0.1 to 0.9. It *might* equate to `1.0`, but `i` in the loop might never even be `1.0` because floating point numbers are "broken" when it comes to adding the inevitably inexact coding of `0.1` added to itself 9 times and expecting it to equal `1.0`. If the card number was entered digit by digit: keep it thus if you want to examine each digit.

Comment: You should include cs50 tag

Comment: @Sanjay-sopho: why? Nothing in the question requires it (unless you'd also include [tag:software], [tag:programming], and [tag:credit-card).

Comment: You could read the credit card number as a string; then you have the digits all separated nicely for you.  You can convert each digit character to a number easily enough (subtract the character code for digit zero, aka `'0'` — noting that this is quite different from `'\0'`).

Comment: @RadLexus: The question comes from a CS50 problem set; such questions should be tagged with [tag:cs50] so that they can easily be found by others studying the course.  You could consider nominating the question for migration to [CS50 Stack Exchange](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: But @JonathanLeffler, the *provenance* of a question is not an issue to close, migrate, or (even) answer/not answer a question on Stack Overflow? What I mean is that the question is about some code of which no part uses anything in the cs50 header, and - looking at it - neither does an answer require it.

Comment: @RadLexus: Alternatively, remove all mention of CS50, then.  That's the first paragraph and the first sentence of the next paragraph.  As long as the question doesn't show up on the SO search criterion '`[c] -[cs50] is:q cs50`', I'm not going to care whether that's because its got the tag or lost the reference to CS50.  There are 8 questions which match that search accidentally — I aim to keep it that way.  (No; I'm not happy about those 8, but there isn't a way to fix them easily.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put in a vector, or kind of it, 16 digits of a number (long int)?

When you % a number by 10, you get the last digit of it, like this:

```
13%10 = 3
3%10 = 3 (03 = 3)
523%10 = 3
```

So, if you %10 you get the last digit and put in your vector, and than you /10, because /10 will remove the last digit, the one that you have already saved.

If you want, I can try to code it, but I think that you've already that kind of done.

Comment: It's implied that I didn't heard anything about arrays and vectors yet. But it's a good one, thank you a lot. I was already suggest to dance around ASCII, so I guess it's a key here. No need to code, I just looked for idea. Thank you again, have a great day.

Comment: Oh, ok. If you only wanted the idea, ignore the second part where I meant to "store" your data. Have a great day =)